# ElasticSearch error ""Message":"Request size exceeded 10485760 bytes"

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk

While uploading a 50 mb size huge JSON string in ElasticSearch using this method -

```
public static void postData(String json, String index, String type) {
    RestClient client = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(testHostPreProd, 443, "https")).build();
    HttpEntity entity = new NStringEntity(json, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    Response response = client.performRequest("POST", "/" + index + "/" + type + "/_bulk",
            Collections.<String, String>emptyMap(), entity);

    client.close();
}
```

The error is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: POST https:someURL/indexHere/typeHere/_bulk: HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large
{"Message":"Request size exceeded 10485760 bytes"}
```

Putting a counter in the code that works send 10k batches might work but I'm not sure how to do that.

Any suggestions on how to handle this issue?

Comment: What is your `http.max_content_length` set to? This indicates that the default is `100mb` so you should be able to index a `50mb` document: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html

Comment: If you are using hosted Elastic on AWS there is a network limit depending on instance size https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-limits.html

Answer (score 0):

For downloading a big amount of records you can use Scroll API:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/scroll-api.html

The mechanism is quite simple:

1. You create a query and give the chunk size, i.e. number of records for a single download – let's say 10.
2. It returns your [ten] records and a `scroll_id` which is the marker to the last document that you have downloaded.
3. If there are more records (20) it goes to step 2. If there are no records, you delete the scroll.

Something like this:

```
Request request = new Request("GET", "/" + index + "/_search?scroll=1m");
request.setEntity(new NStringEntity(jsonQuery, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));
Response response = client.performRequest(request);
String scrollId = jsonNode.path("_scroll_id").asText();

//Extract data you need

//Repeat the scroll, by passing scroll_id

Request scrollRequest = new Request("GET", "/_search/scroll");
scrollRequest.setEntity(new NStringEntity("{\"scroll_id\": \"" + scrollId + "\"}", ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));
response = client.performRequest(scrollRequest);
responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
scrollId = jsonNode.path("_scroll_id").asText();
```